# Microsoft Visual Studio - Unable to open script task in SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have an SSIS Package(2012) in Microsoft visual studio..When I right click and edit it..I get the following error :

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

The task with the name "Map Network Drive" and the creation name "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" is not registered for use on this computer.
Contact Information:
Script Task

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I am not able to open edit any task

Answer (score 7):

The issue may occur because the Script Task is not installed properly. Please check whether the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll` file exists in the following folders (supposing it is a 64-bit platform):

1. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks
3. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

If the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll` file is missing in any of the folders, copy one (from the other folders or a different working SSIS server) to the folder. Alternatively, you can also use the command line tool `gacutil.exe` to install the task assembly into the global assembly cache (GAC).

Comment: I've tried maybe 10 different posts on how to fix this, and I'm pretty sure this one was the kicker. To be clear, I also reinstalled SSDT (2013 and 2015).